# Spectrum of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Consider $R:=\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+3)$. $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[X]$, which is the disjoint union of $\operatorname {Spec} \mathbb Q[X]$ and $\operatorname {Spec} \mathbb F_p[X]$ for every prime $p$.

Thus I would find separately the subsets $\operatorname{Spec} R\cap \operatorname {Spec} \mathbb Q[X]$ and $\operatorname{Spec} R\cap \operatorname {Spec} \mathbb F_p[X]$, whose disjoint union will be $\operatorname {Spec}R$.

The ring of polymomials in one variable over a field is a principal ideal domain, so $1$-dimensional: $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Q[X]/(X^2+3)$ consists then of one point, since $X^2+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. One can repeat the same argument for those $\mathbb F_p$ where  $X^2+3$ is irreducible too.

Is this a good approach? I know very little of field theory, so I wouldn't know if determining for which $p$ the polynomial $X^2+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_p$ is simple or not; at least it didn't seem immediate to me. Should I think of something else or insist this way?

Comment: Looks like you can use that general program, but I'm not an expert on that. Only commenting on the last paragraph. Reducibility of $x^2+3$ over any field surely depends on the existence of $\sqrt{-3}$ in that field. On the other hand, $\sqrt{-3}$ is intimately tied to certain roots of unity. Combine that with the fact that the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, so it contains those roots of unity if and only if... (primes $\le3$ are exceptional and need to be dealt with separately).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it is clear that $\sqrt{-3}$ exists off a cubic root of unity exist. We know that such cubic roots form a cyclic group of order $3$ and so $p-1$ must be divisible by $3$;  conversely if $p-1$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $3$, this group consists of the cubic roots of unity. Is this the argument I should use?

Comment: Correct @Ezio. That's the argument I had in mind. You can equally well use the argument from Rodrigo's answer(+1), if you are familiar with the law of quadratic reciprocity. They give the same result, of course :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track! Figuring out whether $X^2 + 3$ is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_p [X]$ amounts to knowing whether $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ (that is, are there solutions to $X^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{p}$?). For this, you would use quadratic reciprocity.

$$ \left( \frac{-3}{p} \right) = \left(\frac{3}{p} \right) \left( \frac{-1}{p} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} + \frac{3-1}{2}\frac{p-1}{2}} \left( \frac{p}{3} \right) = \left( \frac{p}{3} \right)$$

Hence, it will be reducible exactly when $p = 2,3$ or $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and ireducible otherwise.